# Is it ok to static_cast a void* pointer

Tags: c++, casting

For example, propose `map<int,void*>hold` where `void*` is always storing pointers from `classA` is it safe to cast it back later via static_cast?

```
classA* ptr = static_cast<classA*>( holditerator->second );
```

the reason `void*` is used is because `hold` is member of a class defined on a header used by some cpp files which don't know what `classA` is. I would have to include the header of `classA` definitions on these cpp files which can't be done by many reasons.

Comment: Why would you do this? Please provide more context as there is likely a more suitable solution.

Comment: Why don't you use a map<int, classA*> in the first place ?

Comment: @BatchyX I'm guessing `hold` doesn't only contain classA*?

Comment: Can't you forward declare classA and use classA pointers?

Comment: Using reinterpret_cast would be better as it fits the purpose

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, `static_cast` is OK in that case and the right thing to use.

I have to ask why you don't store `classA*` pointers in the first place though. If you want to put derived class pointers into it, then **beware**, you need to upcast/upconvert (implicitly or explicitly) the derived class pointers to `classA*` *before* you put them into the map.

But even if you put also derived class pointers into the map, a base class pointer would suffice because a derived class pointer is implicitly convertible to a base class pointer.

> The reason void* is used is because hold is member of a class define on a header used by some cpp files which don't know what classA is.

That can be a valid reason to prevent layering violations.

> I would have to include the header of classA definitions on these cpp files which can't be done by many reasons.

That's most probably not necessary in your case. A forward declaration suffices. If the header knows what is put into the map, but just wants to avoid including additional headers, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

As Johannes explained, the `static_cast` is ok. Another technique to prevent the dependencies to `ClassA` in the cpp files is to use the [pimpl idiom](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/).

```
// in header file
class classB {
public:
    classB();
    ~classB();
private:
    class impl;
    unique_ptr<impl> pimpl;
};



// in implementation file
#include "classA.hpp"

class classB::impl 
{
    std::map<int, classA> hold;  // hidden in implementation file
};

classB::classB() : pimpl{ new impl{ /*...*/ } } { }
classB::~classB() { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing void* in the header just because the users of the map should not know about the actual type is *not* a good idea, as you lose type safety everywhere in your code, including at places which do know about ClassA.

Consider

1. deriving ClassA from an class which every part of your code may know about,
2. wrapping the map into an object which provides an interface to those parts of the code that have to deal with the map, but not with ClassA,
3. declaring, but not defining class ClassA in your header file (may be dangerous if objects are destroyed at some place where ClassA is declared, but not defined),
4. using templates,
5. implementing the class *containing* the map as a derived subclass, such that the map field can be put into the derived subclass.

Point 5: Illustration (= template pattern)

Instead of

```
class Containing {
    private:
       map<int,void*> myMap;
    public:
       void somePublicFunction () { // ...implementation }
};
```

you write

```
// Containing.h
class Containing {
   protected:
       virtual void doSomething () = 0;
   public:
       static Containing* Create ();
       void somePublicFunction () { doSomething (); }
       virtual ~Containing () { }
};

// Containing.cc
#include ContainingImplementation.h
Containing* Containing::Create () { return new ContainingImplementation; }

// ContainingImplementation.h / cc
class ContainingImplementation : public Containing {
   protected:
      virtual void doSomething () { // ... }
   private:
      map<int,ClassA*> myMap;
   public:
      virtual ~ContainingImplementation () { }
};
```